# Query Structure Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one of some attributes like this:

[image]

I want to take only the YEAR from that atribute. For your information TanggalMasuk means DATE.

I have query like this:

```
select DISTINCT YEAR(TanggalMasuk), 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Lakilaki` from `kampusmst_orang` 
        LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana` on `kampusmst_orang`.`NIMS1Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.`NIM` using utf8) 
        WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 1 AND `mhsMagister`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)=`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)) AS `Lakilaki`,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Perempuan` from `kampusmst_orang` 
    LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana` on `kampusmst_orang`.`NIMS1Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.`NIM` using utf8) 
    WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 2 AND `mhsMagister`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)=`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)) AS `Perempuan`,


    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Lainlain` from `kampusmst_orang` 
    LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana` on `kampusmst_orang`.`NIMS1Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.`NIM` using utf8) 
    WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 5 AND `mhsMagister`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)=`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)) AS `Lainlain`,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Total` from `kampusmst_orang` 
    LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana` on `kampusmst_orang`.`NIMS1Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.`NIM` using utf8) 
    WHERE `mhsMagister`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)=`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)) AS `Total`

    from `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana` AS `mhsMagister` 
    ORDER BY `mhsMagister`.YEAR(TanggalMasuk)
```

but the result was error. Here is the message error:

[image]

What may I do to fix that? Thans in advance

Comment: YEAR(`mhsMagister`.`TanggalMasuk`)=YEAR(`akdmst_mahasiswasarjana`.`TanggalMasuk`)?

Comment: yes, because I made `akdmst_mahasiswasarjana  AS mhsMagister` @RubensFarias

Comment: just read your query again; you wrote `alias.YEAR(field)` instead of `YEAR(alias.field)`

Comment: Yes. Thankyou for the correction. I really appreciate it @RubensFarias